# How to display product using group by prices in c# console app

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of products which has id, name and price. I want to show it in console using prices such as

Price 1 to 100
--list of products

price 101 to 200
--list of products
and it so on till last highest price.
I need to determine at runtime how many segments I need to create based upon highest price.

Comment: What about prices of `0` or `0.01` or `100.50`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list called `products` that have a property called `Price` you could use a basic `Linq` expression with `OrderBy` and `Where`

**Edit**: now that I understand your question better, you could create a new list for each segment of 100's.

so something like this:

```
products = products.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
var subProducts = products.Where(x => x.Price > 0 && x.Price < 100).ToList();
// then print each item in the list here.
// then do the next segment
subProducts = products.Where(x => x.Price >= 100 && x.Price < 200).ToList();
```

and you could put this basic format in a loop and then iterate through by the 100's to get each segment.

Comment: I used this but how will I group in price of 100s

Comment: I am stuck at one more point where I need to determine at runtime that how many segments I need to create. Like if my highest price is 1140 then I would need to create 11 segments.

Comment: `products.Max(x => x.Price)` will give you the highest price, then you can determine the number of segments from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```cs
var query = products
   .GroupBy(p => (int)(p.Price / 100))
   .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
   .Select(g => new {
      Lower = g.Min(x => x.Price),
      Higher = g.Max(x => x.Price),
      Items = g.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList())
   })
   .ToList();
```

It will return list of lists.

Comment: this is working as expected as I can determine how much segments needs to be created but how will I take the lowest and highest price in each sub list.

Comment: Min and Max functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to solve here. First, you need to figure out, for any given price, how to categorize it into a price range. The information you've given in your post isn't quite specific enough unless all your prices are in whole numbers, but I'll make an educated guess here.

```
// Model
record ProductPriceRange(decimal Low, decimal High);

// Desired behavior
GetPriceRange(0.01m).Should().Be(new ProductPriceRange(0.01m, 100m));
GetPriceRange(100m).Should().Be(new ProductPriceRange(0.01m, 100m));
GetPriceRange(100.01m).Should().Be(new ProductPriceRange(100.01m, 200m));

// Implementation
ProductPriceRange GetPriceRange(decimal price)
{
    var groupBasis = (int)(((price - 0.01m) / 100)) * 100 + 0.01m;
    return new ProductPriceRange(groupBasis, groupBasis + 99.99m);
}
```

Then your grouping code can look something like this:

```
var productGroups =
    from p in products
    group p by GetPriceRange(p.Price) into g
    select new {
        PriceRange = g.Key,
        Products = g.ToList()
    };
foreach (var g in productGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{g.PriceRange.Low} - {g.PriceRange.High}: {string.Join(", ", g.Products)}");
}
```

Sample output:

> 0.01 - 100.00: Product { Price = 0.01 }, Product { Price = 99.99 }, Product { Price = 100 }
> 100.01 - 200.00: Product { Price = 100.01 }, Product { Price = 199.99 }, Product { Price = 200 }
> 200.01 - 300.00: Product { Price = 200.01 }

Comment: This result not displaying the result as expected but displaying result as - Product ranges from 600.01 - 700.00
Models.Product, Models.Product, Models.Product, Models.Product

Comment: @niler: That's because your `Product` class doesn't override ToString. My main point was to show how you could group the items into a model: you never specified how you wanted the output to appear. Try replacing `g.Products` with `g.Products.Select(p => ...)` where `...` renders what you want to see about each product.